# How to export n-quads from blazegraph

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases, triplestore, blazegraph

I want to export all data from blazegraph in the typical formats. I've found a curl command for triple-format and I've found a curl command for xml/json/.. sparql result format

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9999/bigdata/namespace/YOUR_NAMESPACE/sparql --data-urlencode 'query=SELECT * WHERE{ ?s p ?o } LIMIT 1' --data-urlencode 'format=json' > outputfile
```

However what I really need is to generate an export in n-quads format. The graph-information is crucial for my systems. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible using regular `SPARQL`. But you may try other alternatives, e.g. using the provided REST API [link](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/REST_API#GETSTMTS)